# Apply different CSS to all nested divs using query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to apply z-index to each of the nested divs. Its to hard to code css for every div in style.css. So that i'm using jquery to fetch this goal but no luck. Here's the code:

HTML Code

```
<div class="row grid-items">
    <div class="item col-lg-4">
        Box 1
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-4">
        Box 2
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-4">
        Box 3
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-4">
        Box 4
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-4">
        Box 5
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-4">
        Box 6
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-4">
        Box 7
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-4">
        Box 8
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Code

```
$no_of_items = $('.grid-items .item').length;
for ($j = $no_of_items; $j > 0; $j--) {
    console.log($j);
    $('.grid-items .item').css('z-index', $j);
};
```

output:

[image]

i need z-index (8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you missed `var` before `$j`. And `$j` is also not a jquery object (or php variable), so just use `j`

Comment: A few points, firstly run it when the DOM is ready

Comment: Second don't use .each stick with the for loop you've got for better performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
var len=$('.grid-items .item').length;
$('.grid-items .item').each(function(i){
    $(this).css('z-index',len-i)
});
```

**Solution 2:**
Much Better approach by Squint.

```
var len=$('.grid-items .item').length;
$('.grid-items .item').css('z-index', function(i){ return len-i; })
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/056c8jba/)**

Comment: You're fetching `$('.grid-items .item')` over and over again in the loop. Why? Do you expect the `.length` to change?

Comment: Much better. :) One more optimization would be to do `$('.grid-items .item').css('z-index', function(i){ return len-i; })` so that you don't need to create a new jQuery object every iteration.

Comment: @squint: that is pretty cool. i was familiar with text method being capable of doing this. was not aware with .css()

Comment: There are a bunch of methods that have that ability. I have found them very useful.

Comment: @squint it will be even better to cache `$('.grid-items .item')` to prevent two searches in DOM :)

Comment: @Regent: True. Only need to fetch it once.

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to make it in the way you have started:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f85a3nbu/2/).

To set `z-index` for one exact element you can use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var items = $('.grid-items .item');
    var $no_of_items = items.length;
    for (var $j = $no_of_items; $j > 0; $j--)
    {
        items.eq($no_of_items - $j).css('z-index', $j);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS only with the `:nth-child` selector:

```
.grid-items div:nth-child(1) { //first one, give z-index of 8
    z-index:8;
}
.grid-items div:nth-child(2) { //second one, give z-index of 7
    z-index:7;
}
.grid-items div:nth-child(3) { //third one, give z-index of 6    
    z-index:6;
}
```

and so on...

http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/2mu6jhn0/

Comment: @Regent I did consider that before posting but I felt that my solution could add value to this question for someone who may be looking for something similar. After all the question did state "I need z-index (8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)" and not 0 - 500 :-)

Comment: in fact, there may also be a way that you can use the css `counter` to iterate through the elements and adjust the z-index... I'm going to give that a go.

Comment: By the way, is the any way to simplify it using some counters or single line `.grid-items div:nth-child(xxx) { z-index: xxx; }`?